# Visual Studio 2017(15.2) hangs when loading Xamarin projects

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

My Visual Studio 2017(15.2) is hanging every time I load my Xamarin project. I have ReSharper installed. Every time I have to delete (.vs) folder contents to reload the project. Anybody experiencing this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to disable your extensions other than Xamarin and see if ReSharper or another extension is to blame?

Comment: Try installing Visual Studio 2017 Preview (15.3 Preview 7). We saw similar issue, contacted MS team, they found the root of that and fixed it in Preview build.

Comment: Installing Visual studion 2017 Preview(15.3) fixed the issue.

Comment: Do you still have this problem with latest stable release, version 15.6.2? I do, and I have lost a lot of time troubleshooting this. For me however, it does not help to delete the hidden vs folder.

Comment: I also had ReSharper installed. But repairing the Visual Studio installation did not help with this problem. Changing the GUIDs did however. For reference, see my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374422/visual-studio-2017-hangs-while-loading-a-solution).